# Microsoft Word outline bullets beyond set margins

Tags: ms-word

I have set the format of my document to 0.5" margins for all margins. My outline is lettered (e.g. A., b., etc.). The problem I are letters placed within the 0.5" margin on the left aspect of the page. I cannot find a setting or other method (attempted carriage return and indents of various combinations) that resolves the issue.

How do I set MS Word to place the outline headings in the set margins?

I am using Microsoft Word 2016 on a PC with Windows 10 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Left Indent to a negative amount will place the bullet/number in the margin.